# Matching anything between the opening quote and the end of the line

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I'm trying to match dialogue. As in "dialogue from a novel."

I'm using this regex:

`(\")([^"]*)(\")`

Now the problem is that sometimes dialogue omits the closing quote when the dialogue continues on the next line:

```
"Dialogue dialogue."

"Dialogue dialogue. (This dialogue continues in the next line.)

"Dialogue dialogue.

"Diaogue dialogue."
```

I thought I could fix this by treating the end of the line as the closing quote:

`(\")([^"]*)(\"|.*$)`

But the regex is still matching the same bits (illustrated by the `[]`s):

```
["Dialogue dialogue."]

["Dialogue dialogue.

["]Dialogue dialogue.

["Diaogue dialogue."]
```

How to modify the regex so it also matches between opening quotes and end of the line (the second and third line in my example)?

https://regexr.com/620b4

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.  Please show the starting text as a JavaScript string, not as some other markup.

Comment: `"Dialogue dialogue.` <-- should the text here be matched, given that it is not properly surrounded by double quotes?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I want to also match between opening quotes and end of the line.

Comment: `(")([^"]*[^\s])(\s)` Mind you, I have no Idea what I'm doing. I guess that's just matches each "sentence" per row. Not sure what the conditions are to qualify as a "dialouge"

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Hey, I think that regex worked. Would you mind posting an answer with a little explanation? I think it should be`(?=\s)`, though, so it doesn't match empty spaces.

Comment: That indeed works better. Though I only see it do that if there are multiple dialouges per line. Added it into the answer.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Yes, there are multiple dialogues per line: https://regexr.com/620i5

Comment: You may try: `"([^"\n]*)(?:"|$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting for a while, I found out this regex does it:

`(\")[^\"\n]*(\"|\n)`

`(\")`: Match opening quote.

`[^\"\n]*`: Don't match quotes or new lines.

`(\"|\n)`: Match quotes or new lines.

https://regexr.com/620i5

Answer (score 1):

Using `(")([^"]*[\S])(?=\s)` Matching each new sentence starting with `"`, ending at first whitespace that isn't enclosed by a `"`.

I hope that's a proper explanation. Else someone that actually knows about RegEx feel free to explain it.

Comment: What does the `[^\s]` do here?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. I've never written a RegEx in my life, and I just wrote stuff until it worked.  And I just realized that you can just use `\S` instead, since that's the already inverted one.

Comment: @alexchenco There seems to be a problem with this if the last "Dialouge" isn't followed by any whitespace at all. `(?=\s|")` seems to fix it? But misses the last quote. It works with `(\s|")` but then the spaces are back.

Comment: Yes, I found some problems. I think this regex works: `(")[^"\n]*("|\n)`.

Comment: As long as you don't have a dialouge with only a starting quote, and then a proper one on the same line, like `"Dialogue dialouge   "Dialogue dialouge"` Mine would match it as two dialouges. But then I'm not sure how to handle it, and if it's an edge case even worth considering.